# When I use code with a generator in it - cmd freezes

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to code a pin validator and the result is always "False" even though the pin includes only 4 numbers and no letters(It must include only 4 numbers and no letters).

```
def numbergenerator():
    number=999
    while number<9999:
        number+=1   
        yield number

def validate_pin(pin):
    true="True"
    false="False"
    if str(pin) in numbergenerator():
        return true
    else:
        return false
print(validate_pin(1234))
```

Comment: That is expected. `str(1234)` is `"1234"`, and that not generated by `numbergenerator`. Why are you using `str` anyway? Can't you do `return "true" if pin in range(1000,10000) else "false"`, after checking `pin` is integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @yarnabrina. You can just do this:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    return pin in range(1000, 10000)

print(validate_pin(1224)) # True
```

The issue with your code is that you are actually converting the pin to string with `str(pin)` and then checking if it lies in the range or `Integer` numbers.

If you instead want your own version to work, then this would:

```
def numbergenerator():
    number=999
    while number<9999:
        number+=1   
        yield number

def validate_pin(pin):
    true="True"
    false="False"
    if pin in numbergenerator():
        return true
    else:
        return false

print(validate_pin(1224))
```

I've just removed the `str` from your code.